# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable how to parse python dict

Tags: python

```
mydict =  { 
'ServiceResult': { 
'msgBody': { 
  'itemList': [{ 
    'busRouteId': '100100016', 
    'busRouteNm': '110A', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '100100015', 
    'busRouteNm': '110B', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '165000146', 
    'busRouteNm': '1100', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '165000147', 
    'busRouteNm': '1101', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '218000011', 
    'busRouteNm': '1100', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '222000074', 
    'busRouteNm': '1100', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '235000085', 
    'busRouteNm': '1100', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '234000879', 
    'busRouteNm': '1101', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '204000082', 
    'busRouteNm': 'G8110', 
    }] 
 } 
} 
}
```

i want to print all of itemList's 'busRouteId' 
so i write a code:

```
for i in len(mydict['ServiceResult']['msgBody']['itemList']): 
    print(mydict['ServiceResult']['msgBody'][i]['busRouteId'])
```

but it doesn't work and just see this error :

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
```

How to parse python dict?
How can i modify it??

Comment: `for i in range(len(...)):`, or just `for item in mydict['ServiceResult']['msgBody']: print(item['busRouteId'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `range()` with `len()`, and you need to use the `'itemList'` inside the loop as well

```
 for i in range(len(mydict['ServiceResult']['msgBody']['itemList'])):
    print(mydict['ServiceResult']['msgBody']['itemList'][i]['busRouteId'])
```

Or simply iterate over the items in `'itemList'`

```
 for item_list in mydict['ServiceResult']['msgBody']['itemList']:
    print(item_list['busRouteId'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate integer because `len` function return an int. You should use range in the outer place:

```py
mydict =  { 
'ServiceResult': { 
'msgBody': { 
  'itemList': [{ 
    'busRouteId': '100100016', 
    'busRouteNm': '110A', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '100100015', 
    'busRouteNm': '110B', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '165000146', 
    'busRouteNm': '1100', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '165000147', 
    'busRouteNm': '1101', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '218000011', 
    'busRouteNm': '1100', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '222000074', 
    'busRouteNm': '1100', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '235000085', 
    'busRouteNm': '1100', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '234000879', 
    'busRouteNm': '1101', 
    }, { 
    'busRouteId': '204000082', 
    'busRouteNm': 'G8110', 
    }] 
 } 
} 
}
item_list = mydict['ServiceResult']['msgBody']['itemList']
for i in range(len(item_list)): 
    print(item_list[i]['busRouteId'])
```